# Google Drive API IOS change mime type

Tags: google-drive-api

How do I change the mime type to a google spreadsheet?  For some reason @"application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet" doesn't convert my "csv" to a true google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your csv into a Google spreadsheet you don't have to specify the spreadsheet MIME type, but instead upload it normally and add the `?convert=true` query parameter to your request URL:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie at this.

Where do I add that at?

GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-excel"];

GTLQueryDrive *query2 = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

Comment: You have to use the convert parameter of queryForFilesInsertWithObject: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLQueryDrive.h#388

Comment: That worked but when i try to update that file, i get an error.  I can't fetch the file with my fetcher